# C# sync'ing bindingsource and underlying datasource

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview, datatable, bindingsource

Currently having issues with referencing row data in a databound datatable.
The binding is configured as follows:
DataGridView => BindingSource => DataTable

The datagridview allows multiple row selection and sorting.

I have a button which initiates some methods based on the selected datagridview rows:

```
ItemsBindingSource.DataSource = dataSets.Tables["ItemList"];

foreach(DataGridViewRow SelectedItem in datagridview1.SelectedRows)
{
     string SelectedItemName = SelectedItem.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
     int rowPosition = ItemsBindingSource.Find("Name",SelectedItemName);
     RunSomeMethod(dataSets.Tables["ItemList"].Rows[RowPosition]);
}

void RunSomeMethod(DataRow row)
{
    // run some code and modify the values of particular cells within the 
    // row and save the changes
}
```

My issue is that when I sort the Datagridview, the rowPosition for the selected item no longer matches the row position of the BindingSource's underlying datasource. I need some advice on getting the bindingsource and it's underlying datasource to sync, or perhaps a better way of accomplishing this task altogether. Appreciate any advice.

*EDIT

I have realised I can reference the row based on Primary Key value, example:

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow selectedItem in datagridview1.SelectedRows)
{
int selectedItemPrimaryKey = selectedItem.Cells[0].value;
RunSomeMethod(dataSets.Tables["ItemList"].Rows.Find(selectedItemPrimaryKey));
}
```

Not as pretty as I had hoped, but seems to be doing the job. Still open to other suggestions. I am quite new to databinding.

Comment: You can use Gridview_RowDatabound event for your change.

Comment: Apologies, I should have specified I am using WinForms. As far as I can tell there is no RowDatabound event for a DataGridView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another column which called "RowID" which has unique number for all row. and Then find row with this column instead of Row index.
Let me know if u help this, and feel free for further help.

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion. I can see how this would work, however I was hoping to not add a column to my datatable purely for the purpose of recording each row's original row index. I did some more investigation and realised I can find a row in a datatable based on the primary key value. This will solve my problem. Although not as elegant as I was hoping. [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y06xa2h1(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: I must apologise, What you have suggested is exactly what I ended up doing. What you have called a "RowID" is what I already have in place as my primary key.